# Will I be charged for GKE Autopilot if I didn't run anything?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

If I have installed Google kubernetes autopilot cluster and didn't install anything on it, will I be charged?

Here

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview

is a statement

> You only pay for the CPU, memory, and storage that your workloads request while running on GKE Autopilot.

On the other hand, it is hard to believe, that it will allocate nodes for me, but doesn't charge.

Comment: In a sense, it does not allocate `your` nodes. It allocates workloads to shared nodes that Google owns/manages/controls. Similar to how Google charges for Google Cloud Run managed.

Comment: I see nodes with `kubectl get nodes`, are they shared?